# Images issue in WinForms RichTextBox

Tags: .net, winforms, image, richtextbox, rtf

I have an application that writes text with image asynchronously to the RixhTextBox. All works fine, except when i minimize window then restore it to check progress and all images after minimizing and before restoring are not floated to the next line. It looks like this:

[image]

Red line shows what happened while window was minimized.
Code that inserts text:

```
txtLog.AppendText(" ");
txtLog.InsertImage(Resources.OK);
txtLog.AppendText(" " + message + Environment.NewLine);
```

Dont understand what difference between minimized\maximized writing to RTB and how to resolve this.

Comment: you can download it here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx, but i think the issue is not in insert image RTF, because insertion though the Clipboard produces the same results

Comment: Unable to duplicate with WinXP and .NET 3.5.  ExRichTextBox.InsertImage states 'image is inserted wherever the caret is.'  AppendText doesn't, however.  Put debug logic to see if txtLog.SelectionStart is changing when minimized.  If not - try forcing it.

Comment: Works perfect! It indeed didn't set SelectionStart when window was  minimized in tray, strange enough. I just added txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.TextLength; before writing. Please post this as answer, I'll vote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExRichTextBox.InsertImage states 'image is inserted wherever the caret is.' [RichTextBox.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) doesn't, however.

Put debug logic to see if txtLog.SelectionStart is changing when minimized. If not - try forcing it

Edit: Good to hear it worked